# adding a black overlay to an image that is not a background image wordpress posts plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins, tags, posts

I would like to add a black overlay to an image that is not a background image.

I've tried using following code but doesn't work,

`background-color: black, opacity: 0.5;`

I also can't lay another div on top of it as it's a plugin and sometimes takes a little while to load

this is the current css code for it

```
.flexslider .slides img {
max-height: 700px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
width: 100%;
background-color: black;
margin-top: -2%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
```

Comment: .flexslider .slides { background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important; } Add the background-color to the container containing the image not the image itself

Comment: please add url for better understanding

Comment: @VasimVanzara the site on my localhost

Answer (score 0):

You should use pseudo element ":after" :

pseudo elements cant be used on img, you have to use it on parent div

```
.flexslider .slides{
  //blablabla
  display : inline-block;
  position : relative;
}

.flexslider .slides:after{
  position : absolute;
  content : " ";
  top : 0;
  left : 0;
  height : 100%;
  width : 100%;
  background-color : black;
  opacity : 0.5;
}
```

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/eQCuFekdKwrBrm9U0gmg?p=preview, perhaps give us your html too